# DRF: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'DeferredAttribute'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am creating ecommerce api using Django Rest Framework.

This is my order model. I have 2 many to many fields for address and order items.

```
class Order(models.Model):
    payment_options= (
        ('COD', 'Cash on Delivery'),
        ('BANK', 'Bank Transfer'),
        ('WALLET', 'Wallet Transfer'),
    )
    delivery_options= (
        ('Placed', 'Placed'),
        ('Processing', 'Processing'),
        ('Delivered', 'Delivered'),
        ('Cancelled', 'Cancelled'),
    )
    order_number = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    items =  models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
    order_address = models.ManyToManyField(Address)
    delivery_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False)
    price = models.FloatField()
    payment_method = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=payment_options)
    delivery_status = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=delivery_options, default='Placed')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order_number']

    def __str__(self):
        ord = str(self.order_number)
        ord_text = "Order #"+ord
        return ord_text
```

Here is my Serializer:

```
class OrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    prod = ProductSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
        fields = ["quantity", "prod"]

class AdressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields =[
            "address_1",
            "address_2",
            "city",
            "state",
            "postcode",
            "country"
        ]

class CompleteOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    items = OrderItemSerializer(many=True)
    order_address = AdressSerializer(many=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields =[
            "order_number",
            "items",
            "delivery_date",
            "price",
            "payment_method",
            "delivery_status",
            "order_address",
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ord_id = []

        address_data = validated_data.pop('order_address')
        print(address_data)
        for j in range(len(address_data)):
            address = Address.objects.create(
                address_1=address_data[j]['address_1'],
                address_2=address_data[j]['address_2'],
                city=address_data[j]['city'],
                state = address_data[j]['state'],
                postcode=address_data[j]['postcode'],
                country=address_data[j]['country']
            )
            ord_id.append(address.id)

        item = validated_data.pop('items')

        ids = []
        
        for i in range(len(item)):
            prod = item[i]['prod']['name']
            count = item[i]['quantity']
        
            product = OrderItem.objects.create(
                prod=Product.objects.get(name=prod), 
                quantity=count
            )

            ids.append(product.id)

        Order.order_address = Address.objects.filter(id__in=(ord_id))
        Order.items = OrderItem.objects.filter(id__in=(ids))
        Order.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return Order
```

And the POST and GET requests

```
class OrderApiView(APIView):
    """
    A simple ViewSet for viewing and posting orders.
    """
    def get(self, request):
        order = Order.objects.all()
        serializer = CompleteOrderSerializer(order, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    
    def post(self, request):
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = CompleteOrderSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Thank you so much for your any help. Whenever I make post request, data are saved in Database but when it comes to show Post Response it says

```
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'DeferredAttribute' .
```

What's the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this fixed serializer

```py
class CompleteOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    items = OrderItemSerializer(many=True)
    order_address = AdressSerializer(many=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields =[
            "order_number",
            "items",
            "delivery_date",
            "price",
            "payment_method",
            "delivery_status",
            "order_address",
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        addresses = []

        address_data = validated_data.pop('order_address')
        print(address_data)
        for add_d in address_data:
            address = Address.objects.create(
                address_1=add_d['address_1'],
                address_2=aadd_d['address_2'],
                city=add_d['city'],
                state = add_d['state'],
                postcode=add_d['postcode'],
                country=add_d['country']
            )
            # if your address_data only includes required data you can do this instead
            # address = Address.objects.create(**add_d)
            addresses.append(address)

        items = validated_data.pop('items')

        order_items = []
        for item in items:
            prod = Product.objects.get(name=item['prod']['name']) # if you have the prod id it's better to use than to look up by name
            quantity = item['quantity']
        
            order_item = OrderItem.objects.create(
                prod=prod, 
                quantity=quantity
            )
            order_items.append(order_item)


        order = Order.objects.create(**validated_data)
        order.items.set(order_items)
        order.order_address.set(addresses)
        return order
```

I don't get why you might have multiple addresses for the same order, maybe it's a bug from your side or a feature ?
You were also trying to set `Order.order_address` which is not a valid operation, you'll need to create a new Order object and give it the required data.
Also since you are creating the related objects, you have access to them so no need to keep track of ids only then fetch them again.

note that you can also use your other serializers to create your objects (if you want to do that) in place of `model.Objects.Create` for example

```py
address = AdressSerializer(
        address_1=add_d['address_1'],
        address_2=aadd_d['address_2'],
        city=add_d['city'],
        state = add_d['state'],
        postcode=add_d['postcode'],
        country=add_d['country']
    )
```

which is useful if you need to override the serializer's `create` method for them too

Comment: Thank you so much Jimmar. But it again shows "Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use items.set() instead."

Comment: @KanchanBhatta my bad, I've updated the answer (changed the last 4 lines)